# How to write a value in a web form text field using C# Desktop Application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a desktop application using which user can save his/her username and password in desktop application and when user visits that specific website username and password will automatically be filled on a web form text field.
Is there any possibility to send a value from desktop application to a web form (text field)?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hope that you are looking for [this control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6t65c4y(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks For Your Response :). But brother I'm looking for something using which I can set values in text field of web form using desktop application. Let me make it more clear, Step 1. User save password in a desktop application. Step 2. now user visit facebook.com and click desktop application button so that username and password automatically write in text field of a website.

Comment: Even if it may(may not be) possible, there will be big security vulnerabilities, beware for them before initiate the work

Comment: I'll take care of it :) but I'm developing for my internal use only because I'm running a marketing house where different employee use to login to facebook account (provided by company) now to make those password secure I was willing to develop an application where password would be pre-saved in a desktop application and user will only use that application so that my password leak problem will be solved :) if you can suggest a better solution to this problem (i.e. password leak) will b appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever considered a chrome extension ?

Comment: Yeah, Currently I'm using chrome extension and my entire work is done manually because chrome extension is not allowing me load remote script that's why I turned towards desktop application.

Comment: Stepping back a bit: Dashlane does exactly this (including security) for $40/year/person.  Password sharing between users is pretty robust. Several other choices on market, too.  Is there a reason you want home brew?

Comment: Reason behind home brew is that I'm also a developer and why should I buy from a third person when I can develop it by myself :) Yeah it definitely requires some effort though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you are trying to build something thats very similar to what bots do. So maybe you should search for that instead of winforms?